# HERE MAP API issue with Android Native SDK

Tags: android, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I have ingrate the HERE MAP Android native SDK in my app, and i getting the following issue, can any one help me.

1.) Here Map very first time loading issues, but when i close or kill the app and again re-start it then it is working fine.

```
  private void setheremap() {

        mapFragment = getMapFragment();

        mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(
                    final Error error) {
                if (error == Error.NONE) {
                    map = mapFragment.getMap();

                    // Set the zoom level to the average between min and max
                    map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);


                    moveCameraFirstMyLocation();
                    Utils.hideCustomProgressDialog();


                   } 
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

2.)and second is Location bound issues.

```
 GeoBoundingBox geoBoundingBox=GeoBoundingBox.getBoundingBoxContainingGeoCoordinates        (geoCoordinateList);
            map.zoomTo(geoBoundingBox,map.getWidth()-150,map.getHeight()-150,Map.Animation.LINEAR,0);
            map.setZoomLevel(14);
```

Comment: Could you provide the exact type (Lite, Premium etc) and version(4.1, 3.15 etc) of SDK used in your code?
regarding to item 1： was there any error message pop up on screen, or blank screen? Any screen shots available to further check the issue?
regarding to item 2: what is the exact issue? any error message?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport

Hello Team, i am using the android SDK premium edition version 3.15.

 1： was there any error message pop up on screen, or blank screen? Any screen shots available to further check the issue? 

- it is not showing any error messages

 2: What is the exact issue? any error message? 
 - It central bonding issues like we have dropped 3 multiple pin in the map, but it does show in proper screen, we need to make it centralization

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport can i get any responce from your side.

Comment: Regarding to your first issue, could you try "Troubleshooting SDK Initialization Errors" in https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/dev_guide/topics/development-tips.html, and see if that can help. Regarding to second issue, we were not able to reproduce the issue, could you provide more code around the bounding box part? For example any action triggered the zoom to bounding box?

Comment: Regarding to your first issue, could you try "Troubleshooting SDK Initialization Errors" in developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/3.15/dev_guide/…, and see if that can help. Regarding to second issue, we were not able to reproduce the issue, could you provide more code around the bounding box part? For example any action triggered the zoom to bounding box?